# How to use operator[] on a template in a recursive function

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, operator-overloading

I'm trying to write some code that will go through a nested vector of some unknown depth and check if the indexes we want to access are within the vector; if not, I would like to add empty nested vectors (again, of some unknown depth) until we reach those indexes.

For example, a nested vector like `{ { { "a" }, { "b" } }, { { "c" } } }` has data at indexes [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1] and [0, 1, 0]. If we try to access the vector at index [0, 1, 1] and set that equal to "d", the function will expand the vector to `{ { { "a"}, { "b" } }, { { "c" }, { "d" } } }`.

My thought is to use templates to achieve this, like so (the bottom code doesn't set a value, just to keep it simple):

```
template<typename T>
void checkVector(T&& vec, vector<int> indexes, int counter = 0) {
    // Base Case
    if (counter > int(indexes.size()) - 1) 
    {
        return;
    }

    // Add to vector
    while (indexes[counter] > int(vec.size()) - 1)
    {
        vec.push_back({ {} });
    }

    // Recursive
    checkVector(vec[indexes[counter]], indexes, counter++);
}
```

The recursive part does not work, however, because using the operator[] on a template changes the type, so it will not compile. So I have two questions:

1. How do I index into a template and tell the compiler it also has the same properties of template T?
2. Is this even the right way to do something like this?

Thanks all! Let me know if I'm being unclear about anything.

Comment: I would change `T&&` to `vector<T>&` instead, and then if needed provide an overload of `checkVector()` to handle the case when `T` is not a `vector` ie when `vec[indexes[counter]]` happens to return a non-nested non-vector element.

Comment: Thanks Remy! This works great. I attach this code as an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regular `if` all branches should be valid within template.

You might use `if constexpr` (or overloads) to have different paths.
But condition should be a `constexpr` (so cannot depends of parameter's value).

You might for example do:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void setVectorAt(std::vector<T>& vec,
                 std::vector<std::size_t> indexes,
                 const U& value,
                 std::size_t counter = 0)
{
    // Add to vector
    vec.resize(std::max(1 + indexes[counter], vec.size()));
    if constexpr (std::is_assignable_v<T, U>) {
        vec[indexes[counter]] = value;
    } else {
        setVectorAt(vec[indexes[counter]], indexes, value, counter + 1);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rnTPbxW3r)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking at this thread later, I went ahead and wrote up Remy's suggestion for how to handle the recursive vector:

```
template<typename T>
void checkVector(vector<T>& vec, vector<int> indexes, int counter = 0) {
    if (counter > int(indexes.size()) - 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    while (indexes[counter] > int(vec.size()) - 1)
    {
        vec.push_back({});
    }

    checkVector(vec[indexes[counter]], indexes, counter + 1);
}

template<typename T>
void checkVector(T&& t, vector<int> indexes, int counter) {
    return;
}
```